# Can you disable edge gestures in a Windows Store App?

Tags: windows-store-apps

System.EdgeGesture.DisableTouchWhenFullscreen can be used in a desktop app to disable edge swipes, but has no effect on a Store App. We will be using a Store App on a kiosk - is there any way to stop the edge swipes, charms bar app closing gestures?

Comment: Are there any news here?

Comment: Probably best to use Windows 8 Embedded.